# Pycryptodome: AES CBC mode Error 65537

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto, cbc-mode, pycryptodome

I have to decrypt Data with AES in CBC Mode and Zero-Byte-Padding.
Heres my Code (similar to the one in the [Documentation](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#cbc-mode)):

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64decode
from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import unpad

key = b64decode('QkFDR0FubzR0WkdIUkp2WQ==')
iv = b64decode('zBN6M2DMdbAsLcSc')
ct = b64decode('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')
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
pt = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ct), AES.block_size)
print("MSG:", pt)
```

So here are my questions:

1. If i run it I get this Error: *ValueError: Error 65537 while instantiating the CBC mode*. It occurs when it runs line 8 (cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv) and i don't know why. I saw the other Question about that error, but there he tried to decrypt an input, that wasn't declarated, which doesn't seem to be the case here.
   **Solved:** Like 'SquareRootOfTwentyThree' said, the length of my IV wasn't correct... Base64 encodes 8b to 6b. I will post the updated code with the (new) Questions under this.

   ```
   from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
   from base64 import b64decode,b64encode

   key = bytes.fromhex('42414347416E6F34745A4748524A7659')
   ct =b64decode('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')
   iv = ct[:16]

   ciph = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
   res = ciph.decrypt(ct[16:])
   print(res)
   print(b64encode(res))
   ```
2. The task I have to solve says, the msg uses Zero-Byte-Padding (Null-Padding) and if I i run it i get Zero-Bytes at the end. So Can i assume the decryption gone right? Because the thing is, I cant read the secret out of the message..

Thank you in Advance!

Greetings, 
SomeDude

Comment: Your IV is 12 bytes, but it needs to be 16 bytes for AES.

Comment: True, thank you! I realised this yesterday, but didn't had to time to update this, so sorry..